# Joomlas submenu does not work correcly

Tags: drop-down-menu, joomla, menu, joomla3.0, selected

I am using Joomla 3.6.5.

Using standard modules:

- Using level 1 menu in the top.
- Same menu but starting form level 2 (and more) to the left.
- A standard breadcrumb in the middle to show articles (and it's "you are here" in the bottom).

I have 2 problems:

- Dropdown (on selected) does not work when you begin at level 2. Either you have to see everything - and it's a very long list, or you can only see the level 2 items.
- You don't see which menu item that is selected on the side menu.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Or maybe I have to download some more advanced menu plugin?

Comment: Forgot to say I use the theme theme protostar.

Answer (score 0):

Got the second part to work (to see selected submeny item). Added this to template.css (row 3019):

```
.nav-pills > .current > a,
.nav-pills > .current > a:hover,
.nav-pills > .current > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f2981d; /* Or standard #005e8d*/
}
.nav-pills ul a,
.nav-pills ul a:hover,
.nav-pills ul a:focus {
    padding: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav-pills ul > .current > a,
.nav-pills ul > .current > a:hover,
.nav-pills ul > .current > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f2981d; /* Or standard #005e8d*/
}
```

Also had to change the Modules Menus - Menu Class Suffix to " nav-pills nav-stacked"